# How to Export or Import complete database to another database using c#

Tags: c#, import, export

Please help me to create a Export like Export and Import Opttion in in SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/162986-database-backup-restore-through-C.aspx) or [this](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20040913.asp)?

**EDIT**: Here is another [example](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread125044.html).

Comment: Thank u. But i want Sql Server Database to Sql Server Database
Ya thak u .Second one .But i unable to under stand code.
Could u help me to get it in easy way

Comment: Excuse me? Neither your question nor comments make any sense to me.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to be spoon fed everything instead of doing some trial and error. That is not what this site is here to do.

Comment: Sorry for that, i understand, what i want

Comment: @gmcalab I agree with you, but I just wanna help. @kiran you should improve your English skills.

Comment: WE ALL HERE TO HELP EACH OTHER. THIS IS WHAT THIS SITE IS HERE TO DO. Q&A

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20040913.asp) an example.

Answer (score 0):

SqlBulkCopy can be used to import/export data to/from a SQL Server database.
Here is an article articles with example code:
www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Cs_CSV_import_export.aspx

Also SMO can be used as in this example code from Microsoft on how to backup and restore a database with C#:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133.aspx.

Comment: Thanku u r Example is very useful for me

Comment: If one of the answers given gave you what you needed then you should "Accept" it. This will remove this question from the "Unanswered questions" list.
"To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green."

Answer (score 0):

Just send the needed sql statement to the server with a `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

For Backup:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [YourDatabaseName] TO  DISK = N'FileName' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'YourDatabaseName', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

For Restore:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [YourDatabaseName] FROM  DISK = N'FileName' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
```

Or if you like just use (like already mentioned by others) the [SqlBulkCopy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).